# Open, copy, paste close and loop files in a folder

Tags: vba, loops

I have a folder with 50 excel files I need to open, copy, paste, close and open the next one.
The macro is working until the loop, but it is not opening the next file. It stops
Any suggestion?

```
Sub open_and_close()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As Variant
Dim LC3 As Long
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook

Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook

MyFolder = "C:\Users\x\y\z\Test script\"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.xlsx")

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (MyFolder & MyFile)
    Set WB2 = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test Script Scenario 1").Range("J3:J99").Copy
    WB1.Sheets("Test Script Scenario 1").Activate
    LC3 = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Cells(3, LC3 + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Cells(1, LC3 + 1) = Dir(WB2.Name)
    WB2.Close savechanges:=False
    MyFile = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I always avoid DIR as it behaves strange if called several times.
I assume that's your problem - as you call Dir(wb2.name).

Try using FilesystemObject.
You have to add a reference to your project:
[image]

Furthermore it's not necessary to copy/paste >> see sub copyRangeValues

Plus: consider using a table (Insert > table) than it is much easier to add new columns.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Const pathToFiles As String = "C:\Users\x\y\z\Test script\"

Private Const SourceSheetname As String = "Test Script Scenario 1"
Private Const SourceAddressToCopy As String = "J3:J99"

Private Const TargetSheetname As String = "Test Script Scenario 1"
Private Const TargetStartRow As Long = 3




Sub readDataFromFiles()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

Dim SourceFolder As Folder
Set SourceFolder = fso.GetFolder(pathToFiles)

Dim SourceFile As File, wbSource As Workbook

For Each SourceFile In SourceFolder.Files
    If SourceFile.Name Like "*.xlsx" Then
        Set wbSource = getWorkbook(pathToFiles & "\" & SourceFile.Name)
        copyDataFromSource wbSource
        wbSource.Close False
    End If
Next

End Sub




Private Sub copyDataFromSource(wbSource As Workbook)

Dim rgSource As Range
Set rgSource = wbSource.Worksheets(SourceSheetname).Range(SourceAddressToCopy)

Dim rgTargetCell As Range
Set rgTargetCell = getTargetCell

copyRangeValues rgSource, rgTargetCell

'add filename to row 1
rgTargetCell.Offset(TargetStartRow - 2).Value = wbSource.Name

End Sub




Private Function getTargetCell() As Range

Dim wsTarget As Worksheet: Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheetname)

'I copied your code - but it looks weird to me
'think of using a table and then your can work with the listobject to add a new column
Dim LC3 As Long
With wsTarget
    LC3 = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

Set getTargetCell = wsTarget.Cells(TargetStartRow, LC3)

End Function




Public Sub copyRangeValues(rgSource As Range, rgTargetCell As Range)
'generic routine to copy one range to another
'rgTargetCell = top left corner of target range

Dim rgTarget As Range
'resize rgTarget according to dimensions of rgSource
With rgSource
    Set rgTarget = rgTargetCell.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
End With

'write values from rgSource to rgTarget - no copy/paste necessary!!!
'formats are not copied - only values
rgTarget.Value = rgSource.Value

End Sub




Private Function getWorkbook(FullFilename As String) As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FullFilename)
Set getWorkbook = wb
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

First collect the files in an array, then process the files.

```vb
Sub open_and_close()
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As Variant, Files As Variant
    Dim LC3 As Long, NumFiles As Long, Idx As Long
    Dim WB1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook
    
    Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\x\y\z\Test script\"
   
    ' First collect the files in an array
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.xlsx")
    NumFiles = 0
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        NumFiles = NumFiles + 1
        If NumFiles = 1 Then
            ReDim Files(1 To 1)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve Files(1 To NumFiles)
        End If
        Files(NumFiles) = MyFile
        MyFile = Dir()
    Loop
    
    ' Then process the files
    For Idx = 1 To NumFiles
        MyFile = Files(Idx)
        Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & MyFile)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test Script Scenario 1").Range("J3:J99").Copy
        WB1.Sheets("Test Script Scenario 1").Activate
        LC3 = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Cells(3, LC3 + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Cells(1, LC3 + 1) = Dir(WB2.Name)
        WB2.Close savechanges:=False
    Next Idx
End Sub
```